# getting issue while using loadModules in our twig file

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I am getting issue while using loadModules in the twig file, getting error **loadModules is not defined** I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am configuring the route correctly. from controller.

```
/**
     * @Route(
            "/products/add", 
            name="wk_customer_frontend_seller_add_product",
            defaults={"type": "storefront"},
            methods={"GET", "POST"}
        )
     * @Layout
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array|RedirectResponse
     */
```

in layout.yml

```
layout:
    imports:
        -
            id: oro_customer_page

    actions:
        - '@setBlockTheme':
            themes: 'WebkulMarketplaceBundle:Product:createStepOne.html.twig'

        - '@add':
            id: main_content_add_product
            parentId: page_content
            blockType: body
            options:
                attr:
                    entity: '=data["entity"]'
                    form: '=data["form"]'
                    isWidgetContext: '=data["isWidgetContext"]'
                    src: '="layout-build/" ~ context["theme"] ~ "/app.js"'
                    publicPath: '="layout-build/" ~ context["theme"] ~ "/"'
```

now in twig file I am calling like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      loadModules(['jquery'], function ($) {
          $('select[name^="oro_product_step_one[type]"] option[value="configurable"]').remove();
      });
</script>
```

please help me as I have tried all the things I can do, but still getting the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your inline script is executed before main script is loaded.
(`layout-build/" ~ context["theme"] ~ "/app.js"` is loaded at the end of the page).

Never the less, I would recommend avoid using inline scripts, it is bad practice. See article https://doc.oroinc.com/3.1/frontend/javascript/how-to-replace-inline-javascript-with-component/

Comment: 1. could you please let me know, why the main script is not loading any possible way to load the script. I will not use but I want to know about this.

2. Also, the link you have provided it is used for the orocommerce 3.1 and in oro-commerce 4.1 the requirejs is removed so how can I use the page component in orocommerce 4.1.

Comment: 1. main script is loaded at the end of a page as it is recommended in best practices. If you need to add other scripts to the page declare it to `scripts_after` placeholder https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/WindowsBundle/Resources/config/oro/placeholders.yml and be sure it will be executed after main script is loaded.  
2. the article is not about RequireJS or Webpack, it is about replacing inline code of any kind with components declared via HTML attributes. Don't focus on RequireJS in examples, it can be any kind of inline code.